# NoMethodError: undefined method count in rspec while testing my mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I try to test my mailer, but I have an error on my `.count` ,
Here is my `Mailer.rb`

```
def prices_mailer(recipient, prices, sender)
    @sender = sender.fullname
    email = recipient.email
    @name = recipient.fullname
    @prices = prices
    @prices_count = @prices.count

@subject = 'test'
set_meta_data(__method__)
mail(to:email, subject: @subject, from: sender)
end
```

while I try to test with rspec this is what I'm doing

```
describe 'prices_mailer' do
    let(:price) { create(:price) }
    let(:recipient) { 'John.doe2@gmail.com' }
    let(:sender) { 'John.doe@gmail.com' }
    let(:mail) { described_class.prices_mailer(recipient, price, sender_email) }
end

it 'renders the headers' do
      expect(mail.subject).to eq('test')
end
```

When I run the specs, I have the following error :
`NoMethodError: undefined method count for #<Price`

Is anyone knows how to fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mailer expects an array or ActiveRecord relation as the second argument:

```
def prices_mailer(recipient, prices, sender)
```

The argument name is plural and you're calling `#count` on it.

But your specs are passing a single price:

```
described_class.prices_mailer(recipient, price, sender_email)
```

Either update your specs to send in an array:

```
described_class.prices_mailer(recipient, [price], sender_email)
```

or update your mailer to handle a single price:

```
def prices_mailer(recipient, prices, sender)
  prices = Array(prices)
  #...
```

`Array(prices)` will handle arrays, AR relations, single values, ... for `prices`.